# Hostname Detection PHP

Tags: php

how to detect Hostname, like on http://www.whatsmyip.org/more-info-about-you/ at Hostname: Your.Hostname. I need it for my own PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo gethostname(); // may output e.g,: sandie

// Or, an option that also works before PHP 5.3
echo php_uname('n'); // may output e.g,: sandie
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.gethostname.php

Comment: that give me srvXX.000webhost.com but that page reffered to php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php and i used http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae971fc9adfbb11c08ad757fa9b33d59056cf5c3 and thanks for that site page.